# I cannot add time range to fluentd index on kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I cannot add time range to fluentd index

**GET fluentd**
https://justpaste.it/8acsk

if i create from dev tool. I can add date, but if I select I cannot any data

```
POST /fluentd/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type":   "date",
      "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share `GET fluentd`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 1 [date field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) in the mapping.

check your mapping from DevTools =>

```
GET index_name/_mapping
```

Comment: I added from dev tool "PUT fluentd
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_second"
      }
    }
  }
}"
Time range is opened but no results this time

Comment: I added GET index_name/_mapping

Comment: You must be able to use the `date` field as the timestamp field in the Kibana index pattern.